# String formation from hex string

Tags: c++, openssl, sha1, ofstream

I m trying to create hash of file by reading its content, and then hashing it using `SHA1`, after this I m trying to create a filename with this hash value, but the issue only first two char of hash string is taken.
Hash function

```
void hash(const std::string& content, std::string& retValue, bool isFile)
{
    SHA_CTX ctx;
    SHA1_Init(&ctx);
    SHA1_Update(&ctx, content.c_str(), content.size());
    if (isFile) {
        FILE* f = fopen(content.c_str(),"r");
        assert(f != NULL);
        char buffer[1024]={0};
        while(fgets(buffer,1024,f))
            SHA1_Update(&ctx,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        fclose(f);
    }

    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
    SHA1_Final(hash,&ctx);
    retValue.resize(60);
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH;i++){
        char ch[3] = {0};
        sprintf(ch,"%02x",hash[i]);
        retValue[cnt++] = ch[0];
        retValue[cnt++] = ch[1];
        retValue[cnt++] = ch[2];
    }
    std::cout<<retValue<<std::endl;
}
```

when I print hash value in console I get a valid looking val such as this `51d946cde43e90ec03493f88914ca948b5215916`, but it contains only first two characters in this case '51', I switched to gdb to view the string, gdb shows me the string in a weird way `51\000d9\000\064\066\000cd\000e4\000\063e\000\071\060\000ec\000\060\063\000\064\071\000\063f\000\070\070\000\071\061\000\064c\000a9\000\064\070\000b5\000\062\06 1\000\065\071\000\061\066`. I am saving file with `std::ofstream`. I have looked at prev answers that said this is a bug in gdb so it prints like this, but here I can see file getting created doesnt with only first char of hash.
Why is this happening? 
Thank You. 
-----------------------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------------
From comment of dvix, it got resolved, I was copying '\0' with ch[2], so basically I was needed to only copy first two character from each hex character, ch[0] and ch[1] and then place null at very end of string.
so the code inside of for loop should look like this

```
for(int i=0;i<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH;i++){
        char ch[3] = {0};
        sprintf(ch,"%02x",hash[i]);
        retValue[cnt++] = ch[0];
        retValue[cnt++] = ch[1];
    }
    retValue[cnt] = '\0';
```

Comment: `retValue[cnt++] = ch[2];` This copies the `'\0'` nul terminator after each 2 hex characters. But you only want the nul terminator at the very end of the string.

Comment: Negative voters should comment what are they finding in this, so I dont repeat it again. Thank you

Comment: @dxiv okay let me try that

Comment: @dxiv thanks for this comment, it solved my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly shorter version that does the same thing:

```
for(int i=0;i<SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH;i++){
        sprintf(retValue + cnt,"%02x",hash[i]);
        cnt += 2;
    }
```